Where can I get a replacement decorative glass pane for my garage door?
One of my garage door windows is cracked and I believe it's a piece of custom glass. I tried searching and I can't find the exact piece or really anything close to it.
I don't want to replace all the windows if I don't have to. It's a Clopay door and the insert is roughly 40x12. This seems to be a standard size and they make several trim inserts, but I can't find this glass anywhere.
If nothing else, how would I describe this glass? Any search for "decorative" seems to come up with leaded  or etched designed.


Do you have a local glass shop, other than an auto window business? They can cut glass to size and shape, and if you bring a good enough picture they can advise you on whether installing the replacement is within your DIY capabilities or not.

Have you contacted Clopay?  They should be able to direct you to a dealer/ installer that may have or can order the part.

@DrMoishePippik it's glass
